# Create row in the bottom of dataframe which counts the number of occurences of

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a row in the bottom of a dataframe which counts the number of occurences of a given number (0 in this case) appears in each column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Bread':[1,"Nan",3.3, 0],
           'Butter': [2, 3, "Nan", 1],
           'Jam': [0, 0, 0.3, 0.7]})


print (df)
Bread Butter  Jam
0     1      2  0.0
1   Nan      3  0.0
2   3.3    Nan  0.3
3     0      1  0.7
```

My expected outcome would be (with additional row "Occ")

```
print (df)
    Bread Butter  Jam
    0     1      2  0.0
    1   Nan      3  0.0
    2   3.3    Nan  0.3
    3     0      1  0.7
   Occ   1      0    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to check which values are `0` and take the [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), `rename` the resulting series and [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) as a new row:

```
df = df.append(df.eq(0).sum(0).rename('Occ'))

     Bread Butter Jam
0       1      2  0.0
1     Nan      3  0.0
2     3.3    Nan  0.3
3       0      1  0.7
Occ     1      0  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and count `True` values by `sum` and create new row by [`setting with enlargement`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc['Occ'] = df.eq(0).sum()

print (df)

    Bread Butter  Jam
0       1      2  0.0
1     Nan      3  0.0
2     3.3    Nan  0.3
3       0      1  0.7
Occ     1      0  2.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.eq(0))
   Bread  Butter    Jam
0  False   False   True
1  False   False   True
2  False   False  False
3   True   False  False

print (df.eq(0).sum())
Bread     1
Butter    0
Jam       2
dtype: int64
```